# Why is this simple username sys not working?

Tags: javascript, chat

I want to create a chat system (which i already accomplished), but a working username selector, and it gets the username in the input, then when the user sends a message via chat, it is their username!! And also, i tried putting it in a localStorage, so when the user refreshes or rejoins, the name is still there and not removed! I think im close, but it says UNDEFINED, which really got me confused? Please help? Thanks!!

```
localStorage.playerusername = document.querySelector(".hud-name").value;
let username = localStorage.playerusername;
let chatMsg = [];

function appendChatMessage(currentUserName, chatMessage) {
  let chatElem = document.createElement("p");
  chatElem.innerHTML = "<strong>" + currentUserName + ": </strong>" + chatMessage;
  document.querySelector(".chat").appendChild(chatElem);
}

for (let i = 0; i < chatMsg.length; i++) {
  appendChatMessage(username, chatMsg[i])
}

let Game = {
  currentGame: {
    variables: {
      
      sendMessage: function(messageContent) {
        chatMsg.push(messageContent);
        appendChatMessage(username, messageContent);
        document.querySelector(".enterT").innerHTML = ""
      },
      
      addChatTopRemoverPackage: async function() {
         if (chatMsg.length == 7) {
          let chatElem = document.querySelector(".chat")
          if (chatElem.children[0]) {
            chatElem.removeChild(chatElem.children[0])
            if (chatMsg.length > 0) {
              chatMsg.shift()
              //if (chatMsg.length == 0) {
                //chatMsg.pop();
              //}
            }
          }
        }
      },
      chatRemoverRefresher: setInterval(() => {
        Game.currentGame.variables.addChatTopRemoverPackage()
      }, 0.000000000001)
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="hud-name-select
          type-text  
          maxlength-16
        ">
          <input class="hud-name" type="text" maxlength="16" placeholder="Enter Nickname...">
          <div></div>
          <div><br></div>
          <button class="btn-play btn-green background-color-green">
            <div style="
              display: none;
              " display="none">Loading......<div></div>
            </div>
            <span>Play</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="msgcont">
      <div class="messages">
        <h1>
          CHAT
        </h1>
        <div class="chat">

        </div>
        <div>
          <input class="enterT" type="text" placeholder="Enter A Message..!"><button
            onclick="Game.currentGame.variables.sendMessage(document.querySelector('.enterT').value)">send
            message</button>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
```

***Kevin***

Comment: Please take a look how to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I did, but i don't know what is wrong. Please help and explain :D??